# Phonegap GPS permissions

Tags: javascript, cordova, geolocation, ios8

How can I change the permissions for my PhoneGap application? I want the app to access the user's GPS. But do not really know how I do it when I use the build.phonegap.com me to retrieve the app. The app never asks for permission to use my location. Instead, I put on it manually but still I get the error code "Permission denied".

iPhone 5s IOS8, 
org.apache.cordova.geolocation 0.3.10,
Phonegap 3.5

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReadyGeo, false);

function onDeviceReadyGeo() { 
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, onError, {timeout:10000});
  } else {
    error('Geo Location is not supported');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to show a permission dialog on **iOS**, you have to configure below in the **config.xml**.

```
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription" overwrite="false">
    <array>
      <string>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</string>
    </array>
</gap:config-file>
```

I use this and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've looked at the [Cordova plugin docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html), and have the basics of the plugin setup.  If so, it's probably a permissions issue.  Getting location permissions is a bit more complicated with iOS8, as you have to consider which permission you are asking for separately for iOS8+ and iOS7 and earlier.

Check out [this NSHipster article](http://nshipster.com/core-location-in-ios-8/) for more details, but basically:

- For iOS8 you must have either the "When In Use" (NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription) or "Always" (NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription) permissions, which you get by putting the equivalent keys and descriptions in your Info.plist
- For iOS7 and earlier, you need to have the NSLocationUsageDescription key and description set

Cordova will look to see that these requirements are met before returning the location.